# Statistical significance in known population

Tags: p-value, population, bioinformatics, genetics, sequence-analysis

I am working with a data set with the sequence identity (a value in [0,1] representing the conservation between sequences) of many genes for many bacterial strains. I would like to be able to draw conclusions about how statistically significant a value for one gene is by comparing it to the distribution of all genes for a given pair of strains. These distributions are strongly skewed towards 1.

While the sequences were identified using prediction algorithms that likely missed a few genes, we are operating under the assumption that almost all genes have been captured, and thus I have sequence identity values for the full population in question, not just a sample. In order to conclude that a given value is significant, are statistical tests needed here, or is comparing the value with the cumulative distribution to calculate the p-value sufficient?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm a bit unclear about the statement "I would like to be able to draw conclusions about how statistically significant a value for one gene is by comparing it to the distribution of all genes for a given pair of strains." It would help if you could provide a simple example of how you propose to do that. Also, there seem to be a few types of "populations" here: bacterial strains, genes, and gene variants among strains; only the population of genes is fully captured. Please edit the question to address those issues, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the question is actually addressing but I think you have the sequence identity values for all the genes of interest, so there's no need for statistical tests to understand the significance of a specific gene value. Instead I guess, you could for example simply analyze the distribution of these values to see where a particular gene stands compared to the others.

To check if a gene's value is statistically significant, you can simply calculate the p-value by comparing it to the empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF)

If the p-value is low it suggests that the gene's sequence identity value is significantly different from the rest. This could mean that the gene is more or less conserved between the bacterial strains than the other genes.

I hope this clears it.